# Response.OutputStream.Write() Show data to browser Instead of Download

Tags: c#, asp.net, filestream, httphandler

I use IHttpHandler to Download a file from Server.Everything works fine.
But it shows the data on browser instead of download it. I need to download the file from the server like we do download from other servers.

Could anyone suggest me, what should I do to download the file,
Or what is the convenient way to download a file(pdf,mp4 etc).

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string strPathName = "";
        if (context.Request.QueryString["fileName"] != null)
        {
            strPathName = context.Request.QueryString["fileName"].ToString();
        }
        string filename = context.Server.MapPath("~/MyPath/" + strPathName);

        System.IO.Stream oStream = null;

        oStream =
            new System.IO.FileStream
                (path: filename,
                mode: System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                share: System.IO.FileShare.Read,
                access: System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        try
        {
            context.Response.ClearHeaders();

            context.Response.Buffer = false;

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";


            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment");

            long lngFileLength = oStream.Length;

            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", lngFileLength.ToString());

            long lngDataToRead = lngFileLength;

            while (lngDataToRead > 0)
            {

                if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                {

                    int intBufferSize = 8 * 1024;

                    byte[] bytBuffers =
                        new System.Byte[intBufferSize];

                    int intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream =
                        oStream.Read(buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0, count: intBufferSize);

                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write
                        (buffer: bytBuffers, offset: 0,
                        count: intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream);

                    context.Response.Flush();

                    lngDataToRead =
                        lngDataToRead - intTheBytesThatReallyHasBeenReadFromTheStream;
                }
                else
                {
                    lngDataToRead = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            if (oStream != null)
            {
                oStream.Close();
                oStream.Dispose();
                oStream = null;
            }
           context.Response.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your content-disposition header looks incomplete. Old but still relevant: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/May/21/Downloading-a-File-with-a-Save-As-Dialog-in-ASPNET

Comment: Hello ADyson,
Thanks for your response. I read your mentioned post and try to implement but get the same output.The file convert to byte and shows the byte value to the browser.

Comment: Can you show your changes please? You do need to specify a file name. Also you should probably send the correct MIME type, if you can.

Comment: I remove all the code from ProcessRequest and add below code

 string filename = context.Server.MapPath("~/test/myImage.jpeg");
 context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
 context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myImg.jpg");
context.Response.TransmitFile(filename);
context.Response.End();

Comment: And what happened? It still displays in your browser? Do you see the image, or something else? And also how are you calling this code from the client?

Comment: Hi ADyson, I just checked the code in ASP.net MVC and the code works fine.But I tried the code in a visual web GUI project. I create a Handler and call the handler in button click like below

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/DownloadFile.ashx?fileName=myImage.jpg");

in response it returns some base64 type text and rendered it on the browser, instead of download it.

Comment: So to be clear, you are downloading direct through a hyperlink, not via an ajax call or anything, is that right? And what is "visual web GUI"?

Comment: Hi Adyson,
Visual WebGui is a new AJAX framework that took a different approach to web application development.
I am downloading through button click event (like Asp.net web form have).

The framework generate ajax call behind the scene. I checked the request on browser developer tool.` Content-Disposition` header is added on the request, but it does not download the file, it shows the file in browser

Comment: you can't directly download a file via ajax, it only returns the data into a JS variable in the page's code, instead of triggering a traditional request and download. Your button needs to make a standard HTTP request, not an ajax call.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
May be that is why I am unable to download the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly download a file via ajax, it only returns the data into a JS variable in the page's code, instead of triggering a traditional request and download.

Your button needs to make a standard HTTP request, not an ajax call.